# Coerce dataframe to numeric, aggregate and how to get string variables back?

Tags: r

For practical reasons I'm coercing a dataframe to numeric and aggregate on selected columns (user defined):

```
# Create dataframe
sample = c("a", "b", "c","c","b","a") 
technic=c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ccc","bbb","aaa")
bool = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE) 
df = data.frame(sample,technic,bool)  

 > df
     sample technic  bool
    1      a     aaa  TRUE
    2      b     bbb FALSE
    3      c     ccc  TRUE
    4      c     ccc  TRUE
    5      b     bbb FALSE
    6      a     aaa  TRUE

# Coerce to numeric
canCoerce <- canCoerce(df,"numeric")
coercable    <- sapply(df, canCoerce, "numeric")
x1 <- sapply(df[, coercable], as, "numeric")

# Aggregate base on a specific column (not always the same, user defined)
adf <- aggregate(x1,by=list(df$sample),FUN=mean)
adf

> adf
  Group.1 sample technic bool
1       a      1       1    1
2       b      2       2    0
3       c      3       3    1
```

How do I get my factors and characters back?

What I want is an aggregated data.frame with all my original character and bool variables.

```
> adf
  Group.1 sample technic bool
1       a      a       aaa    TRUE
2       b      b       bbb    FALSE
3       c      c       ccc    TRUE
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `canCoerce`?

Comment: @PierreLafortune see `?canCoerce` ;-)

Comment: Oh wow, had no idea that was a thing

Comment: What about cases where the mean isn't an integer? Round to the nearest factor? The whole thing seems misguided.

Comment: I agree with you but i don´t a better way to handle the aggregation when your dataframe contains integers, bools and characters. If you think of another idea i take it.

Comment: The problem is that you are not telling us what this will be used for. If this is an intermediate step in a bigger process, maybe we can find a better way.

Answer (score 4):

You can get those character and logical variables back by indexing the the levels of the original variables with the resulting means:

```
adf$sample <- levels(df$sample)[adf$sample]
adf$technic <- levels(df$technic)[adf$technic]
adf$bool <- as.logical(adf$bool)
```

which gives the desired result:

```
> adf
  Group.1 sample technic  bool
1       a      a     aaa  TRUE
2       b      b     bbb FALSE
3       c      c     ccc  TRUE
```

If the `sample` and `technic` are character variables, use:

```
adf$sample <- levels(factor(df$sample))[adf$sample]
adf$technic <- levels(factor(df$technic))[adf$technic]
```

When the resulting mean isn't an integer, you can either use `round`, `floor` or `ceiling` to get integer values.

Comment: The problem is that my data.frame is big and is not always the same, meaning sometimes i can contain character columns , other times a mix of bool and characters and sometimes int, bool and character.
So a more global solution would be better